# Interpret R Squared and RMSE

Tags: r-squared, rms

I am relatively new to using the MLTK app on Splunk.

When trying a number of example, I ran a regression that uses "ac_power" to predict "total-cpu-utilization". I receive the following R squared and RMSE for both training and testing, respectively.
[image]

Since the R squared > 0.9 and the RMSE is similar for both training and testing, can I infer that "ac_power"is a good predictor of "total-cpu-utilization"?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "good."  In some settings an $R^2$ of 0.9 would be fantastic and in others it would be dismal.

Comment: While this can happen by sheer luck, it concerns me somewhat that your out-of-sample performance better than your in-sample performance and leave me wondering if there could be a leak into the out-of-sample data.